# Прокси функция\класс

Tags: python

Постановка задачи.
Есть объект A с методами m1, m2, m3.

```
 A.m1()
 A.m2()
 A.m3()
```

Нужно при каждом вызове метода выполнить дополнительное действие.

```
 print('smt')
 A.m1()
```

Можно ли описать такой класс (или функцию) чтобы он при своем вызове выполнял заранее описанное действие и далее транслировал свой вызов другому классу. Имена методов не известны заранее.
т.е.я запускаю:

```
proxy.m1()
```

а фактически выполняется:

```
print('smt')
A.m1()
```

Answer (score 5):

Для этих целей в `python` предназначен механизм [**декораторов.**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)

*Пример использования может выглядеть следующим образом:*

```
class customDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print "customDecorator.__init__()"
        f()

    def __call__(self):
        print "customDecorator.__call__()"

@customDecorator
def customFunction():
    print "customFunction()"

print "Finished decorating."

customFunction()
```

---

**Данный код, как и ожидалось, выведет на экран следующее:**

```
customDecorator.__init__()
customFunction()
Finished decorating.
customDecorator.__call__()
```

Другие примеры использования можно найти на [**stackoverflow.com**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

---

### Update на основании информации из комментариев.

---

В том случае, если исходный класс не может подвергаться изменениям, то необходимо написать соответствующий прокси-класс. В случае `python` с его `duck-typing` достаточно просто написать класс-обертку *(и, кстати говоря, в этой обертке вполне как возможно использование тех же самых декораторов для удобства).*

```
class LoggingA(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.obj = A(*args, **kwargs)

    def method1(self):
        # ... - здесь добавляется логгинг
        return self.obj.method1()

    def method2(self):
        # ... - здесь добавляется логгинг
        return self.obj.method2()
```

Единственный `corner case`, который не покрывает данный подход - это ошибка, в случае, если в коде есть проверка типа `isinstance(whatever, A)` или `issubclass(whatever, A)`, и для поддержки этого случая пришлось бы написать `forwarding wrapper`.

Другое дело, что вероятность этого достаточно мала, да и многие дискуссии оправдывают сомнительность использования `isinstance` в `generic` коде, поэтому о таких вещах можно не думать.

Comment: Использование декораторов затруднительно, так как объект A описан в модуле, я его получаю непрямо. Т.е. на каком то этапе я просто имею инстанс объекта и все.

Comment: @moden Такие вещи имеет смысл выносить в вопрос) Сейчас заапдейчу.

Comment: Неподходит. "Имена методов не известны заранее."

Answer (score 1):

Легко:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        attribute = getattr(self.__obj, key)
        if callable(attribute):
            def temp(*args, **kwargs):
                print('smt')
                return attribute(*args, **kwargs)
            return temp
        return attribute


class Example:
    obj = 'a'

    def method(self, a):
        return a + 1


p = Proxy(Example())
f = p.method
print(f(1))
print(p.obj)
```